# Howto get snapshot of ubuntu mirror from the past

Tags: ubuntu, repository

I am looking for a way to create a ubuntu mirror for a specific release (say 12.04), which represents a mirror state in the past, say at day X.

Of course I could sync my local mirror on day X, and create a backup of this version, and then just restore that if needed. But because of size consinderations, the backup approach is not feasible.

So basically, there are two questions involved:

1. Do ubuntu mirrors keep all the published package versions? That would be prerequisite - on the ubuntu mirrors I see various versions of packages, but I can not see if these versions belong to the same release or are in different versions because of different releases.
2. Is there a standard way to rebuild a mirror in state X, or will I have to record the exact filenames of day X, and then "manualy" (can be scripted of course) download all the filenames which have been recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. Superseded packages are deleted after about 24h of beeing outdated.
2. No. It seems that superseded package versions are accessible through the [launchpad python api](https://help.launchpad.net/API). I have not checked the details, but will update this post once I know more about this.

The api is rather complex, but it boils down to that you can get a specific package e.g. with

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/<package-name>_<version>_<arch>.deb
```

So to get a complete mirror of day X, one will need to record the package versions of all packages, and then download them. It would also be possible via the python api, there you can get removal and superseded dates for each package.